# What is the difference between 'stat_qq', 'geom_qq' and 'qqnorm' functions in R?

Tags: r, quantile

As far as I understood, all three deliver **quantile-quantile plots**, but couldn't get what's the difference among the three.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `qqnorm` function comes with R, whereas `stat_qq` and `geom_qq` are functions of the `ggplot2` package.

There's no difference in the statistical results. However, we have to enter different amounts of code to achieve similar (sober and publishable) visible results.

In **base R** we simply do:

```
qqnorm(y)
qqline(y, col=2)
```

[image]

In **`ggplot2`** we type:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mapping=aes(sample=y)) +
  stat_qq() + 
  stat_qq_line(color=2) +
  labs(title="Normal Q-Q Plot") +    ## add title
  theme_bw() +                       ## remove gray background
  theme(panel.grid=element_blank())  ## remove grid
```

[image]

As for `stat_qq` and `geom_qq`, I can't see any difference in code between the two, they seem to be synonymous.

---

### Data

```
set.seed(42)
y <- rt(200, df=5)
```

Comment: WOW! It seems whoever wrote `stat_qq` and `geom_qq` in `ggplot2` was being very counterproductive. So, in both cases, first the sample `y` is converted to a standard form by subtracting 'Mean' from each value and dividing by 'SD', and then that's compared to standard theoretical? But when we even don't know for sure that sample `y` is a Standard Distribution, is doing that correct? Bdw, thanks a lot for eliminating the confusion!

Comment: @amsquareb In a Q-Q plot, quantiles of the (theoretical) standard normal are plotted against the same quantiles of the sample. The sample is not standardized; this only appears so because the example data are centered. The core of the `qqnorm` function is how `x` is generated, try: `plot(x=qnorm(ppoints(200)[order(order(y))]), y=y)`, which might clarify things. (NB: For sake of completeness, there's also the `car::qqPlot(y)` function.